# Certbot Multiple plugin: Authenticate with one plugin and configure with another

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I am using certbot's cloudflare plugin to generate a wildcard cert for my domain.

Now I also want to use the `--apache` plugin to update the apache config.

I tried running the following command

```
certbot -d example.in -d *.example.in --dns-cloudflare --apache
```

Obviously the application is throwing the following error.

```
Too many flags setting configurators/installers/authenticators 'apache' -> 'dns-cloudflare'
```

I need cloudflare plugin to auto verify the wildcard dns, But simultaneously I also need the apache plugin to set the config automatically.

Can this be achieved and if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of digging the docs, and enough trial and errors, got it working

For starters, Here is some excerpt from [the official docs](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#combining-plugins).

> To specify a combination of distinct authenticator and installer plugins, specify the authenticator plugin with --authenticator or -a and the
>   installer plugin with --installer or -i.

...And your man did the rest. XD

```
certbot -d *.example.in -d example.in  -a dns-cloudflare -i apache
```

So as I had wished for, we are doing exactly that, we are using  `dns-cloudflare` for authentication [`-a`], and `apache` for installation [`-i`].

Pretty sweet huh?